# Redirect page and edit something in another file

Tags: php, redirect

i have a little problem
I have a form in login.php:
`

```
<form action="loginscript.php" method="post">
    <h2>Login form</h2>
    <label for="nick">Podaj imie: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick">
    <br>
    <label for="pass">Podaj haslo: </label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
    <br>
    <p>LOG IN</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

`

and i have a loginscript.php file:
`

```
<?php
    session_start();
        if (isset($_POST["nick"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) {

        $nick=$_POST["nick"];
        $pass=sha1(sha1($_POST["pass"]));

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "baza2");
        if ($conn) {
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM login_table WHERE nick='$nick' AND pass='$pass'");

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
                $_SESSION["logged"]=true;
                header("Location: main.php");
            } else {
                header('Location: login.php');
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }  
    }
?>
```

`

In the loginscript.php in else i have redirect to login.php page. How can i change maybe p tag from 'LOG IN' to 'USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS WRONG'?

I tried using jquery but that doesn't work, maybe I don't know how. Please help :(

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: There's no point in using `sha1` twice. It's as useless as if you used it once or none at all

Answer (score -1):

You can't change anything on the target page *from there*, but what you *can* do is provide some information to the target page which *that* page can use.  For example, consider this redirect:

```
header('Location: login.php?failed=true');
```

Then in the `login.php` code you can check for the `"failed"` query string value and conditionally change the output based on that.  For example:

```
<?php
  $message = isset($_GET['failed']) ? "USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS WRONG" : "LOG IN";
?>
<form action="loginscript.php" method="post">
    <h2>Login form</h2>
    <label for="nick">Podaj imie: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick">
    <br>
    <label for="pass">Podaj haslo: </label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
    <br>
    <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try the code below.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    $_SESSION["logged"]=true;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'main.php';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Your Password or username is wrong!');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).